# Need to convert to a RAW file for a heightmap in Unity

Tags: image, image-processing, unity-game-engine, heightmap

I need to convert a grayscale heightmap I created into a RAW file to use in Unity. I have searched Google for a way to do this for a couple of hours, to no avail. Is there a way to do this without Photoshop? My file was saved as a JPG, but I could convert to a BMP if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there are plenty of tools which work with the RAW format other than photoshop. Try using http://www.darktable.org/

Also for Unity it's just a matrix of [16 bit integers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/229875/raw-file-format.html) so fairly sure you could hack something up in octave or matlab pretty quickly to do the job.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!